# Ajax is not sending multiselect data to Django views

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I am quite new to Django so bare with me.
I have a multiselct list in my webpage and I need to send  the selected items to my views in order to make use of them.
To do so, I used ajax but when it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

This is the script:

```
 $("#var_button").click(function(e) {
        var deleted = [];
        $.each($("#my-select option:selected"), function(){
                deleted.push($(this).val());
            });
        alert("You have deleted - " + deleted);
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
              type: "post",
               url: "/description/upload-csv/" ,
               data: {
                'deleted' : deleted  }

            }); // End ajax method
    });
```

I checked with alert if maybe the variable deleted is empty but it return the selected values so the problem is in my ajax query.

This is the part where I retrieve the data in my views.py

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        del_var = request.POST.getlist("deleted[]")
    my_class.del_var = del_var
```

I changed the data type to text but it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

I cant help you on the Django side.

```
$.each($('#selector'), (i, e) => {
    deleted.push($(e).val());
})
```

but this will add the value to the "deleted" variable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I made sure that that part of the code works